# Import XSLT scripts containing templates with same names

Tags: templates, xslt

I am making a xslt script that imports two other xslt scripts.
The two imported xslt sxripts contain some templates with the same names.
I'm using xslt 2.0

I have a choose and based on the countrycode either the d96a.xslt sxript is called or the d01b.xslt script is called.
But I need to handle it all in one script.

I have tried to add a use-when to each, but i cannot make it work.

I have d96a.xslt with this template:

```
<xsl:template name="BGM">
        <xsl:param name="C002_1001"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$C002_1001"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

and d01b.xslt with this template:

```
<xsl:template name="BGM">
            <xsl:param name="C002_1001"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$C002_1001"/>
        </xsl:template>
```

And then I have another xslt that uses both of the other files:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:import href="d01b.xslt"/>
        <xsl:import href="d96A.xslt"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:call-template name="BGM">
                <xsl:with-param name="BGM_C002_1001" select="'380'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And now it fails because BGM exists in both the imported xslt scripts.

I tried use-when this, but couldn't get it to work:

```
    <xsl:import href="d01b.xslt" use-when="Party/CountryCode = 'EN'"/>

<xsl:call-template name="Header" use-when="Party[CountryCode = 'EN']">
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to handle this?
I canot change the name of the templates in the imported files.

Comment: Please show the code you currently have ("I have tried to add a use-when"), together with all necessary input files to reproduce your problem. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please also make it clear whether you are using XSLT 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0. Also, we need to understand what you are trying to achieve: do you need to invoke one of these duplicate templates, or both, or neither?